# circular populate throws irrelevant error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm getting this error but there is no virtual in the schema.

`Error: If you are populating a virtual, you must set the localField and foreignField options`

***Schema***

```
let kategoriSchemaObject = {
//...
    kategoriChildren: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Kategori'
    }],
//...
}

let kategoriSchema = new Schema(kategoriSchemaObject , {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Kotegori', kategoriSchema );
```

***Query***

```
Categories.find({
    kategoriUst: null,
})
.populate({
    path: 'kategoriChildren',
    options: {
      limit: 8,
    },
    populate: {
      path: ' kategoriChildren',
      select: 'name',
      options: {
        limit: 6,
      },
    },
  })
  .exec()
  .then((data) => {

//...
    next();
  })
  .catch((err) => next(err));
```

If I remove second populate It works as expected.

Am I missing something here? I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4734) about this.

Comment: idk but there is an extra space in the path `' kategoriChildren'`

Comment: You did created your schema as `Kotegori` and your links as `Kategori`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT thanx man.

Comment: I post it as answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***So as said in comments section***:

There were a space in `populate(...)` description `' kategoriChildren'`.

And the category schema got a misspelled name:

> You did created your schema as Kotegori and your links as Kategori

Comment: I'd just wasted my 3 days and couldn't see that little space :S :S This is not my code. I'm just reviewing this and I think I'm going to kill someone.